# How to use multiple IP block list in Ubuntu peer 2 peer programs?

Tags: iptables, qbittorrent, p2p, vuze

I would like to use several public IP block list (IP filters) in qBitTorrent or Vuze, on Ubuntu 14.

What is the easiest way to do that and to get the lists updated?

*Note: This is not a discussion about wether IP block list should be used or not.*

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using [PeerGuardian](https://launchpad.net/~jre-phoenix/+archive/ppa) to get the lists downloaded and merged:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jre-phoenix/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install pgld pglcmd pglgui
```

PeerGuardian was pretty buggy at startupt in my case but it does merge the lists from bluetack and other providers.

- Run **pglgui**
- On **Configure** tab, choose your lists and click **"Apply"**
- On **Configure** tab, **disable "Start PeerGuardian at system boot"** otherwise you will have
  many problems connecting to the Internet and browsing the Web
- On **Control** tab, click on **"Stop"**

Then put this path in vuze/qbittorent/whatever torrent client ip filter:

```
/var/lib/pgl/master_blocklist.p2p
```

I haven't tried to figure out how to update the lists easily.

*Note that modblock has been replaced by peerguadian.*